# Is it idiomatic to say "Your XYZ Team" in English?

Tags: idiomatic-language, greetings

Like at the end of an email... Or is it not really used?

> Dear XYZ Customers,
>   Thanks for everything.
>   Cheers,
>   Your XYZ Team

Comment: Although Cheers, Used in such a way is chiefly a British usage, it is less common in American English.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly natural to end with

> Your Personal Fitness Team
>   Your Health and Well Being Team
>   [The Customer Care Team](http://www.thecorner.com/system/web/custom/hp/homepage/homepage.jsp?confId=1084)

In a recent mas mailing for the Amazon Web Services conference re:Invent, the email was signed

> Sincerely,
>   The AWS re:Invent Team

Using "your" is not necessary but may be a nice touch depending on context.

Comment: How has it taken 9 months and 8 bumps by the Community user to get a vote on this answer? :shakes head: